# Backup Samba Server with rsync?

Tags: backup, samba

We have a common Samba Server for all the departments. However we are not taking any backup  of this server in other location. Recently this leads a lot of data corruption. And we are unable to restore any those datas. I just want to take a  step forward to avoid this problem in future. Is there a way to backup files which is in  samba server to other location using rsync (incremental backup) ? Pls someone explain it with an  example in  detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rsync command to backup the whole filesystem of a server is:

```
rsync -av --delete --numeric-ids \
    --exclude="/proc/*" \
    --exclude="/sys/*" \
    --exclude="/DIRECTORY/" \
    root@server:/ /backup/directory/
```

Strongly recommended: first run rsync with `-n` option to simulate the transfer, so that you can add specific exclude rules (and check that the `--delete` is not removing wrong files).

You need ssh running on the server you want to backup. You may need to add a SSH key to your server, and put the rsync command in a shell script, run by cron to do nightly backups or so.

`man rsync` is a very comprehensive documentation.